# GitHub actions not identifying environment secret tokens

Tags: github-actions, workflow, vercel, cicd

I recently created two workflows that deploy a preview when a push is made to a non-release branch (incl `main`) and deploys a production build when pushed to the `release` branch. However the preview workflow is failing with the error:

> Error: No existing credentials found. Please run `vercel login` or pass "--token"

On the line: 
`vercel pull --yes --environment=preview --token=`

I've setup the tokens in environment secrets of the repository, and below is the workflow file:

```
name: Preview Deployment
env:
  VERCEL_ORG_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}
  VERCEL_PROJECT_ID: ${{ secrets.VERCEL_PROJECT_ID }}
  VERCEL_TOKEN: ${{secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - release
jobs:
  Deploy-Preview:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: "Echo values"
        run: |
          echo $VERCEL_PROJECT_ID
          echo $VERCEL_TOKEN
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Install Vercel CLI
        run: npm install --global vercel@latest
      - name: Pull Vercel Environment Information
        run: vercel pull --yes --environment=preview --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Build Project Artifacts
        run: vercel build --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
      - name: Deploy Project Artifacts to Vercel
        run: vercel deploy --prebuilt --token=${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}
```

The echo isn't logging anything, not even `***`(Although this isn't any important step, it was just a way to possibly debug the issue). I've followed [this](https://vercel.com/guides/how-can-i-use-github-actions-with-vercel) article from vercel to create the workflow. I'm pretty sure that the tokens are set up correctly, again at the same time, I'm unable to pinpoint the cause of the error. How do I fix this? TIA.

Comment: Try: `echo  ${{ env.VERCEL_ORG_ID }}`

Comment: See [env context](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#env-context) for more details and examples.

Comment: As I said the concern is not really about logging the values, but that was just a way for troubleshooting it. Additionally, I did try it and the result is the same, unfortunately.

Comment: That was for debugging the issue with the correct syntax. If you already have tested with that then you need to verify the secrets in the repo.

Comment: I've added the secret tokens in `settings>enviornment> environment secret`. I have also added the same tokens as environment variables too.

Comment: What about  `Settings > Secrets and variables > Actions > New repository secret`?

Comment: See [Creating encrypted secrets for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/encrypted-secrets#creating-encrypted-secrets-for-a-repository) and [Creating configuration variables for a repository](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#creating-configuration-variables-for-a-repository).

Comment: Great. That fixes the issue. Looks like I'd added the tokens to environment secrets instead of repository secrets. Thank you!